# Draw text on a Rectangle

Tags: java

How can I draw an S inside a filled rectangle? This is what I have so far. I am able to draw an S but its never in the center of the filled square. How to achieve this?

```
g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, i * 20 + 20, j * 20 + 20);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the type of pane you are using. A simple solution would be to use a stack pane which would stack the nodes on top of each other and order it so the rectangle would be first and the text box with the S second 
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm